# Turn ViewModel into QueryString

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a ViewModel that I would like to use to populate the QueryString, almost the opposite of the binding that MVC does out of the box. So for the model that looks like this:

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    public string Keywords { get; set; }
    // more properties here
}
```

I would hope to be able to do something like this:

```
string querystring = AspMagicMethods.GetQueryStringFromViewModel(searchViewModel);
// querystring == ?keywords=booyah&...
```

Obviously I could go through each property and create the string myself, but I was wondering if there's anything built into the framework that might be of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method of MVC to do so from any controller action.

```
var myModel = new SearchViewModel{Keywords ="test"};
RedirectToAction("actionName", "controllerName", myModel)
```

Comment: Sorry, I need to get the QueryString in the code, not when I render the action - this is awesome though, I hadn't thought of that. Updated my question's example for clarification.

Comment: The OP already said he can go through each property and create the string himself, and that he doesn't want to do that, yet this is what you are suggesting.